# OpenGL Program with multiple windows

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm looking for an efficient way to use two separate windows for one OpenGL program in C++. It is a drawing program and like Photoshop or Illustrator I would like to have a tool bar that is a separate window that can be moved around but does not get sent behind the composition window when the user starts to draw. Can this be done?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452806/multiple-windows-in-opengl

Comment: do you really need opengl to render/draw the tool bar? the more usual way is to use buttons and labels using a windowing system (win32/MFC....)